A query on Power Query: Faster way to transfer data from one file to the other
I am currently consolidating financial statements for 2023 with comparative data for 2022 across multiple agencies.
Now, I have to do the following tasks:
A) Make a way so that the previous year's data (2022) from Excel File A will be transferred over in Excel File B efficiently without copy pasting data for 2022 figures from File A to B; and
B) Integrate current year's data for 2023 sent by multiple agencies (100 plus) in their respective columns in File B, also without the tedious copy and paste method.
Example for 1st task:
I want to transfer the 2022 figures of all agencies (LGU A, LGU b, etc) per type of Fund (General Fund, Special Education Fund, Trust Fund) from File A to their corresponding 2022 columns in File B. Problem is there are 100 plus LGUs with 3 separate types of funds that I have to consider. So if I will copy and paste the figures manually, I have to do it 300 times.
Would Power Query help on this? I am still new to this feature of Excel and the tutorials online are too many for me to watch and besides, this is a very specific problem that I have not found a similar situation being tackled in their examples.
If Power Query is too complicated for this, are there any other alternatives to achieve what I want to maximize efficiency for consolidation?File B (data for 2023 and 2022) wherein 2022 data must be transferred here from File A
File A (data for 2022 and 2021) wherein 2022 data must be transferred to File B


Power Query is really designed for combining and transforming tabular/raw data whereas your spreadsheets present summarized data. I would look to another solution to capture the values you want. You may want to use VBA to copy prior year sheets into your current workbook and then build formulas to reference or look up the data.

If I was using power query to perform the task, I would take the 2022 data and unpivot it. I would do the same for 2023 data. Then I would merge the two together and repivot that. The big issue is the lost of of column ordering and realigning that via power query (without account and fund numbers) may be too much to figure out.

The alternative is to use an index/match formulation or similar 2D lookup. But you will need to copy/paste a ton of formulas.  If your data lines up you might also be able to use excel's consolidation feature (but I suspect that won't work).

I do commiserate with you, as a fomer analyst that was responsible for compiling almost 300 funds for a City's annual report. It just may be that you have to suck it up this year, and during the off season figure out the proper queries from your ERP system that gets you to those excel reports without intervention. Good luck.

Your particular scenario sounds a bit tricky, but in general I have found Power Query to be the most productive and effective low-code tool for data transformation tasks.  I have been specialising in those tools for over 20 years now.
Your main challenge is that Power Query works better on data in "tidy data" format (one row per observation), whereas it sounds like your data has observations in separate columns.  Power Query can handle that data, but I would typically use it's UnPivot feature to turn columns into rows early in the query steps, then use it's Pivot feature to transform the rows back into columns near the end of the query steps.
The other alternative to look at is python pandas. This can do magic with data transformation, but it can be very obscure to work with (even if you are a coder). Power Query shows you a data preview at every transformation step so it is a WYSIWYG data editor. python can do that e.g. jupiter notebook with many dataframe displays, but it is not as good a UX.  If your requirements need lambda functions, well they are just totally obscure to test/debug.
